# Lithuanian phone number validation

Tags: php, regex

We have 2 styles of phone numbers:

86 *** ****

+3706 *** ****

*** **** - random numbers

I used this before but now I need to validate both formats.

```
static function isPhoneNumber($phoneNumber) {
    return preg_match('/^[+0-9. ()-]*$/ui', $phoneNumber);
}
```

How to validate these two numbers using regex?

Comment: Do 2 regex... Check if one or the other is fine

Comment: Your actual regex validates both formats. And much more...

Comment: Okey, I will check. My friend said that he can not enter both formats.

Comment: *** **** - random numbers = 123 1234 - 12345678 ???

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
(86|\+3706) \d{3} \d{4}
```

- `(86|\+3706)` looks for either `86` or `+3706`
- `\d{3}` and `\d{4}` look for 3 and 4 digits respectively